# How to download a tar file received in HTTP Response using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a tar file in HTTP response body. I need to download the content as a tar file for the user. How can it be done in javascript?

Comment: use window.location to redirect to the tar file

Comment: Cab u please explain it with an example? @madalinivascu

Comment: yes  `window.location = pat/to/the/file.tar`

Comment: I am getting the content of the file in HTTP response. Using that content I need to give it to the user as another tar file. I don't think using the path will do anything. Can u suggest a way now
? @madalinivascu

Comment: what kind of http response?

Comment: I meant in response body.

Comment: does it have the proper header added to it?

Comment: @madalinivascu There's only one kind of HTTP response...

Comment: This is what i get in response header. @madalinivascu
    Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=installer.tar
    Content-Type:application/octet-stream
    Date:Mon, 12 Sep 2016 04:58:43 GMT
    Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked

Comment: @UtsavSinha my answer bellow should work

Comment: @UtsavSinha Your server should be returning `application/tar` for the `Content-Type` header.  This won't break your download... but you should correct your server's configuration anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about the scenario.  Simply navigate to the URL.

```
window.location = 'http://example.com/your-tar-file.tar';
```

Answer (score 0):

create a html link with the download attribute ,trigger the click attribute for that link

```
<a class="tar-generate" href="path/to/generated/tar" download=download>Download tar</a>
```

js for triggering :

```
$('.tar-generate').click();//trigger('click');
```

if this doesn't work you need to save that generated file to your server using file_put_content or any other file saving function, and then generate a download link

Comment: My mistake, I misread "of the tar file", not "as a tar file".

Answer (score 0):

Make `http` request by passing the `url`, and give a callback function. In the Callback function write your logic

Example code:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

//callback Function
httpGetAsync('https://api.github.com/users/abc', function (response) {
window.location = response.<tarLink> // here give the tar link
})
```